# VirtualEnv and Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, virtualenv

I'll try to explain this, hopefully it makes sense.

I had installed a virtual env a while ago in the directory: `desktop/project_website/test_project/env` and activate it to do some websites.

I also pip installed scrapy on the `desktop/project_website/test_project/env/Scripts` dir

The problem is that whenever I use the command prompt to run scrapy I need to be in this *specific* directory, so all the files that scrapy creates are made in there, not in the directory where my project is (that is `desktop/project_website/Scrapy`)

I already tried setting the path of where scrapy was installed into my project directory:

```
(Test_Project) C:\Users\A\Desktop\Project_Website\Scrapy>path
PATH=%path%;C:\Users\A\Desktop\Project_Website\Test_Project\env\Scripts
```

And getting this error:

```
(Test_Project) C:\Users\A\Desktop\Project_Website\Scrapy>scrapy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Python35\Lib\runpy.py", line 184, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Python\Python35\Lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\A\Desktop\Project_Website\Test_Project\env\Scripts\scrapy.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\users\a\desktop\project_website\test_project\env\lib\site-packages\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 108, in execute
    settings = get_project_settings()
  File "c:\users\a\desktop\project_website\test_project\env\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\project.py", line 68, in get_project_settings
    settings.setmodule(settings_module_path, priority='project')
  File "c:\users\a\desktop\project_website\test_project\env\lib\site-packages\scrapy\settings\__init__.py", line 292, in setmodule
    module = import_module(module)
  File "c:\users\a\desktop\project_website\test_project\env\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'quotes.settings'; 'quotes' is not a package
```

So, in short anyone know what can I do to run scrapy in my project dir? Thanks.

**UPDATE  - SOLVED**: 
Instead of using the to virtual env path`C:\Users\A\Desktop\Project_Website\Test_Project\env\Scripts` I set it to where I installed scrapy on my PC `c:\python\python35\scripts` and it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the python interpreter that occurs first in the paths will be used. You can specifically mention which interpreter to use. Something like this:

```
$ path_to_dir\env\bin\python runpy.py
```